# Passing variable across scripts

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to import a variable from another script! In script blabla2.m I've `[listaDiOggetti addObject:strResult];`

problem is `"Use of undeclared identifier 'strResult'"`

but in the blabla2.h I'm importing with `#import "blabla1.h"`

and in the blabla1.h I've : `@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *strResult;`

Why the blabla2 can't see the variable of blabla1?

Answer (score 1):

Since Objective-C is an Object Oriented language you might want to read up on Classes and Properties in Objective-C: [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

A `@property` is not a variable. It is a property to help encapsulate a class variable.

```
//blabla1.h

@interface Blabla1 : NSObject {
    NSString *_strResult; //Class variable
}

@property (strong) NSString *strResult; //Property
@end

//blabla1.m
@implementation Blabla1

//setup Getter/Setter as strResult using _strResult
@synthesize strResult = _strResult; 

@end
```

So once you have your class variable defined in `blabla1.h` you can access it using the property after you create an instance of `blabla1` like so:

```
Blabla1 *myBlabla1Obj = [Blabla1 alloc] init];
...
NSString *someString = [myBlabla1Obj strResult];
```